Terraform: creating "azurerm_container_app_job" based on a Docker image while said image doesn't exist yet
I want to create a resource of type azurerm_container_app_job, which will eventually run every day at midnight based on a Docker image. But creating this resource requires that the Docker image already exists. This in contrast to creating a resource of type azurerm_linux_web_app, where you can provide the name of a non-existing Docker image and the resource can be created without errors. (The web app won't do anything, sure, but at least we can create it.) This is great if you're still building the Docker image, but want to have all your infrastructure ready after 1 Terraform run. But for a resource of type azurerm_container_app_job this is apparently not possible.
Is there any workaround for this? I want to deploy all my Azure resources in 1 Terraform run. Here is my code for the azurerm_container_app_job:
resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job" {
    
  name                         = "my_backend_job"
  resource_group_name          = <some name>
  location                     = <some location>
  container_app_environment_id = <some id>
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  secret {
    name = "acr-password"
    value = <some secret>
  }
  
  registry {
      server               = <some server>
      username             = <some username>
      password_secret_name = "acr-password"
  }
  
  replica_timeout_in_seconds = 1000
  replica_retry_limit        = 10
  
  schedule_trigger_config {
      
      cron_expression = "0 0 * * *"
      parallelism     = 1
      
  }
  
  template {
      
      container {
          
          name  = "backend-container-job"
          image = "<some not-yet-existing image>"
          command = ["python", "main.py"]
                    
          cpu    = 0.5
          memory = "1Gi"
          
      }
      
  }
    
}


You can use preexisting docker image where it helps in achieving the requirement of creating jobs no need to create the docker image on our won @limitlntegral314


Creating "azurerm_container_app_job" based on a Docker image using terraform

The creation of jobs in container Apps is different from the webapps where you need docker image that need to mandate where as in webapps its not important that the image exists.
As per MSDoc the job configuration must include the docker image to use it to be created.
You can use other any images available in docker composition as per the requirement which are preexisting, and you can be able to achieve the requirement in one go.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "example" {
  name                = "vksbContainerRegistry"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
  admin_enabled       = true
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-environment"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_job" "container_app_job" {
  name                         = "vksbbackendjob"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.example.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  secret {
    name  = "acr-password"
    value = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_password
  }

  registry {
    server               = azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server
    username             = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_username
    password_secret_name = "acr-password"
  }

  replica_timeout_in_seconds = 1000
  replica_retry_limit        = 10

  schedule_trigger_config {
    cron_expression = "0 0 * * *"
    parallelism     = 1
  }

  template {
    container {
      name    = "backend-container-job"
      image   = "Use one preexisting image" 
      command = ["", ""]  

      cpu    = 0.5
      memory = "1Gi"
    }
  }
}

output "container_app_job_id" {
  value = azurerm_container_app_job.container_app_job.id
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-cli
